# try/catch logic, conditional code block inside try or below catch?

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a simple doubt, perhaps a newbie one, but ... See this code:

```
try {
    $em->flush(); // this is Doctrine EntityManager#flush call

    [some code block]
    // some code here and as my business logic requires
    // if flush fails then this code shouldn't be executed
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage());
}
```

Now, if `$em->flush()` fails, PHP will try to execute `[some code block]` or it will goes directly to `catch`? If I don't want the code to be executed if `flush` fails then I should get out of `try{} catch() {}` sentence and put it below? Which is the right way?

Comment: To answer your question, you could've written a [7 line demo to demonstrate](http://3v4l.org/bGOkO) the call behaviour

Comment: If `$em->flush()` fails it will skip the rest of the code in the `try` block and  go straight to the `catch` block.

Comment: As [flush()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#_flush) throws an exception if it fails, failure will jump code execution to the `catch` block, bypassing `[some code block]`

Comment: @kingkero thanks man, I have my code right just that doubt comes to my mind

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what your after but if the flush function is to decide if the try/catch should be run i would go for:

```
if($em->flush()){
  try {


  [some code block]
  // some code here and as my business logic requires
  // if flush fails then this code shouldn't be executed
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want, since `flush` will thrown an exception if it fails, anyway thanks for your answer